# Ethernet on Moto E3 with Marshmallow (6.0)

Tags: usb-on-the-go, lan

Just got a usb2 to ethernet adaptor. I am trying to connect the Moto E3 on wired ethernet but this is unsuccessful so far.

It does not seem to work like plug and play.

*ifconfig* does not shows eth0 in the list. (*netcfg* is not supported by version 6.0.)

I tried the Ethernet USBhost app but it just says Error. ALso tried setting the phone in airplane mode.

Has anyone made this phone working on wired ethernet? What could I check and try?

Comment: If the phone lacks the drivers for the USB Ethernet interface, it'll only work if you use a custom ROM that includes those drivers.

Comment: Thanks. I see. Would LineageOS work for this?